# XAMPP won't start Apache on Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, xampp, ulimit

When I try starting Apache from the XAMPP control panel (Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard), I get the following error popup and Apache won’t start:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl: line 70: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

XAMPP was running perfectly 10 minutes earlier. I stopped Apache to add some `.conf` files and it failed on restart. I removed all the new `.conf` files (i.e. reverted it to how it was before) but now I get the above message.

I’ve checked AppMonitor and I see the `httpd` processes (one by `_www` nested within root). Just tried quitting these but they’re auto-restarted on new process IDs and it didn’t solve the problem.

And I’ve tried a full reboot and I still get the same error (before starting any apps). I’d be grateful if someone has an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about port `80` already being in use. In scenarios like yours, this is commonly caused by Apache already (or still) running.

As you already noticed, there is still an `httpd` process running. Make sure to first exit **all** Apache HTTPD processes and then start it again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the key issue is. How can I be sure all HTTPD processes have been exited (or killed)?

Comment: Usually, they should properly exit when Apache is stopped (for example by using `apachectl`). If due to some error, that didn't happen. You can always force them to shut down by using something like `sudo killall httpd` or `sudo killall apache2`.

Comment: I tried `sudo killall httpd` and it killed the process but then recreated it, just as it did when I clicked Quit Process in App Monitor. The httpd process owned by _www is nested within an httpd process owned by root, which in turn is nested within the launchd process owned by root. Perhaps launchd is restarting it each time?

Comment: Also stop using Skype. Skype uses port 80

Comment: @Sai Not when you disable it. http://i.imgur.com/nkJdUy9.png

Answer (score 0):

This will permentaly disable httpd.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemon/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could be causing the issue: Apple’s built in web sharing service being active or zombie XAMPP processes still being active.

If this is caused by Apple’s web sharing you can handle this all by going to `System Preferences…` and then selecting `Sharing`. Once there, uncheck `Web Sharing`—which is basically just Apache `httpd`—and your problem should be solved.

That said, if this is basically a “zombie” instance of Apache running after some XAMPP tweaks, the best bet is to do something like the following:

First, run [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) (list open files) which will list all of the files actively open on the system.

```
sudo lsof | grep MAMP | grep apache
```

Note the two [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) commands piped together? What I am doing is getting the list of open files, then filtering those which have a file path connected to MAMP—or in your case change that to XAMPP or whatever folder/directory you have it running in—and the I am filtering the `apache` in the pathname. The list should look something like this:

```
httpd     2204            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2211            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2212            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2213            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2214            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2215            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
httpd     2216            jake    2w      REG                1,2     24685 17953784 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
```

Okay, that is a whole list of processes. Apache runs on the concept of there being one parent process with many child processes spawned to deal with traffic. So if you kill a child process, the parent process notices it & respawns a new child.

Now looking at that list, typically the lowest number in that process list will be the parent—since it starts up before the other child process of course—so you should kill that to kill all processes. So in this case, the lowest number process in the list is `2204`, so just run this command:

```
kill 2204
```

And then the parent process is killed and all child processes should drop away as well. Then port `80` should be available again.